# how add flags to python regex?

Tags: python, regex, flags

I want to add a flag to my re.sub regex string.  In PHP, I would just do this '`\test is good\i`'

I tried this in re.compile, but it does not have `.sub` method.  I tried to use `s.replace`, but I cannot add the `i` flag to this as well

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for the `re` module is an excellent place to start.

Answer (score 9):

Compiled regex objects can be passed to `re.sub()`, so flags can still be passed in at compile time.

```
r = re.compile('test is good', re.IGNORECASE)
re.sub(r, 'yup', 'TEST IS GOOD')
```

Alternately, flags can be added with `(?iLmsux)` syntax:

```
re.sub('(?i)test is good', 'yup', 'TEST IS GOOD')
```

Comment: Or yet another variant: `re.sub('test is good', 'yup', 'TEST IS GOOD', flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: You can also use `r.sub`, because regex objects *have* a `sub` method. I don't know what the OP is talking about when he says "it does not have `.sub` method".